# How to share my jar utility with selected buddies only?

Tags: java

I have made some general utilities(jars) for some general purposes.
Some of my friends want these utilities for their use.
I am ready to share my stuff (free of cost), but afraid they don't re-distribute it further.

Is their something in java as described in the following code for my jar's class files.

```
public class UtilityClass{

            static{

                long secretCode = 7534759 ;
                //a hardcoded long value (hardcoded by me for my friend)
                //related to friend's Computer System which either
                // don't changes untill he reformats his computer
                // or is something like motherboard serial number or etc..etc...

                long buddiesSystemSecretCode = getSecretCode() ;

                if( !(buddiesSystemSecretCode == secretCode) ){
                    System.exit(1) ;
                }
            }

            private static long getSecretCode(){
                long secretCode = 0 ;

                //any java code to get friend's System hardware specific code

                return secretCode ;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything simple like that could easily be decompiled and removed.

Why are you scared about the possibility of them distributing the code further? You need to weigh up the cost (in time and/or money) of making your code hard to copy vs the actual damage that redistribution would cause.

Put it this way: PC games companies put a lot of effort into copy protection, and look how quickly games are still cracked. Do you want to go to those lengths? Just how much value are you attaching to this code? Indeed, if it's useful but not commercial, why not just make it Open Source anyway?

Answer (score 4):

If they're your friends, trust them.  Ask them to not distribute your code.

The other alternative is to look into copy-protection schemes, with your friends' email addresses & a hashcode of some sort.  But seriously, if you don't trust them not to forward the files, why do you consider them "friends" and "buddies"?

Answer (score 1):

Put a license notice with your code that no one can redistribute it. Later you can put your friends in jail if they re-distribute your code :)

PS. Go OpenSource.